# CTE not Evaluating All Selection Criteria Correctly

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

Good Morning,

I've written the following stored procedure that searches for records that have one or more charge codes designated as a specified procedure and flags those as ProcGrouper=1 and need to identify those accounts that do not have contrast charges (flagged as ContrastGrouper=0).

When I run the sproc and audit accounts, I'm seeing many that have contrast charges.  Thus, it appears that the CTE is not evaluating all criteria correctly.  How might I remedy this?

```
with cteGrouper
as
(
SELECT [ENCOUNTER NUMBER],
[DATE OF SERVICE], [FEEDER KEY],
[CHGDTL CPT4 CODE], CASE
WHen [FEEDER KEY] IN ('76803520121','76803520120','76803520112','76803520111',
'76803520110','76803520109','76803520108','76803520034','76803520030','76803520027',
'76803520025','76803520017','76803520015','76803520014','76803510073','76803510072',
'76803510064','76803510012','76803510011','76803510008','76803510003','76803510002',
'76803510068','76803520031','76803520028','76803520107','76803520022','76803520020',
'76803520106','76803510009','76803510070','76803510069','76803510067','76803510065',
'76803510074','76704027052','76606123003','76606123001','76606120012','76606111003',
'76606102043','76606100011','76606102040','76606121006','76606121009','76606123002',
'76606102053','76606102042') then 1 else 0
end as ProcGrouper, 
Case when [Feeder Key] in ('76806360076', '76806360077','76806360089','76806360090',
'76306360509','76306360513','76306360514','75706362105','76806366053','75706366054',
'75706366055','76606360099') then 1 else 0
end as ContrastGrouper
FROM ENCOUNTERCHGDTL
where ([Date of Service] between @StartDate and @EndDate)
),
cteFilterAccounts
as
(
Select [Encounter Number],
[Date of Service], [Feeder Key],
[Chgdtl CPT4 Code], ProcGrouper, ContrastGrouper
from cteGrouper
where ProcGrouper=1
and ContrastGrouper=1
)

Select [Encounter Number],
[Feeder Key],
[Date of Service],
[Chgdtl CPT4 Code]
,[ADMITDATE - CCYYMMDD], [DISCHARGEDATE - CCYYMMDD],
[DISCHARGEDISPOSITION], ProcGrouper, ContrastGrouper
from cteGrouper
join Encounter on [Encounter Number]=[EncounterNumber]
and AdmitSubService <>'SIG' 
and HSP#='1'
and ActualTotalCharge>0
where ProcGrouper=1 
and ContrastGrouper=0
and [Encounter Number] not in
(Select [Encounter Number] from cteFilterAccounts)

Order by [ENCOUNTER NUMBER]
END
```

Comment: Perhaps some more detail about what results you got and what you expected to get woudl help us out here.

Comment: @HLGEM  I'm seeing accounts having one of the feeder keys in the ContrastGrouper statement.  I want to exclude such accounts as long as their ProcGrouper evaluates to 1.

Comment: Can there be more than one row with the same account within the specified period? If so, can they have different Feeder Keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redefine your `cteFilterAccounts` CTE. The thing is, your present code for that CTE returns the set where every *individual* row from `cteGroup` has both `ProcGrouper=1` *and* `ContrastGrouper=1`. Based on the code for `cteGroup`, that can never be possible, because a row can have a `[Feeder Key]` belonging to *no more than one* of the two groups, so it's *either* `ProcGrouper=1` *or* `ContrastGrouper=1`, but not both. Therefore, the CTE returns nothing.

Logically, though, you seem to be searching for rows that have both attributes set on the global scale, i.e. *within the period*. One possible solution could be to use a join, like this:

```
cteFilterAccounts AS (
  SELECT g1.[Encounter Number]
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Encounter Number],
    FROM cteGrouper
    WHERE ProcGrouper=1
  ) g1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Encounter Number],
    FROM cteGrouper
    WHERE ContrastGrouper=1
  ) g2 ON g1.[Encounter Number] = g2.[Encounter Number]
)
```

This query joins all `[Encounter Number]` values with `[Feeder Key]` from one group that are found within the period, with a similar list where `[Feeder Key]` belongs to the other group. The matching values give you the resulting set.

Alternatively you could use INTERSECT:

```
cteFilterAccounts AS (
  SELECT [Encounter Number],
  FROM cteGrouper
  WHERE ProcGrouper=1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT [Encounter Number],
  FROM cteGrouper
  WHERE ContrastGrouper=1
)
```

Basically, it uses the same logic as join.

You could also try a completely different approach, grouping, like this:

```
cteFilterAccounts AS (
  SELECT [Encounter Number]
  FROM cteGrouper
  GROUP BY [Encounter Number]
  HAVING MAX(ProcGrouper) = 1
     AND MAX(ContrastGrouper) = 1
)
```

Here you are selecting distinct accounts that have both `Grouper` attributes' *maximum* (aggregated) values equal to 1.

Comment: I implemented your first suggestion.  It worked perfectly!  Thanks much for your help:)